# How do I merge lists with common elements, where these elements themselves are lists/tuples?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, arraylist, set

I have this nested list and I need to loop through it in some way to merge inner lists that have common elements (where these elements are lists in themselves). Here is a simplified data that has the pattern of the existing original data:

```
data = [
        [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]], 
        [[2,3],[4,5]], 
        [[4,5]], 
        [[6,7],[8,9],[10,11]], 
        [[8,9],[10,11]], 
        [[10,11]], 
        [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]], 
        [[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]], 
        [[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]],
        [[18,19],[20,21]],
        [[20,21]]
       ]
```

I want to obtain a merged nested list as given given below:

```
merged = [
      [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]], 
      [[6,7],[8,9],[10,11]], 
      [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]]
     ]
```

Below is what I have tried which unfortunately is not going beyong the second inner `for loop` and is returning the error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'values'`:

```
tmp = {}
for subl in original:
    subl = list(set(subl))                        # Eliminating duplicates by first converting to a set
    subl = dict(zip(subl, range(len(subl))))      # Create dictionary from list
    sublswitch = {y:x for x,y in subl.items()}    # Swap dictionary key for values and vice versa                
    ii = 0
    for key in sublswitch:            
        tmp.setdefault(key.values(), set()).add(list(key.values())[ii])
        ii += 1                                         

out = []
for k, v in tmp.items():
    out.append([[k, i] for i in v])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses O(n) additional space which tracks all sub-lists that are already added using a hash table (thus, all lookups would just be O(1)).

```
added = set()
merged = []

for item in data:
    filtered = list(filter(lambda value: value not in added, map(tuple, item)))
    if filtered:
        added.update(filtered)
        merged.append(list(map(list, filtered)))

print(merged)
```

Output

```
[[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]], [[6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11]], [[12, 13], [14, 15], [16, 17], [18, 19], [20, 21]]]
```

---

**Update**

The solution above only prevents duplicate list items from occurring again on the next list. Here, we wouldn't only prevent them from occurring again but also merge them on existing ones. As a result, the time complexity of this algorithm is somewhat O(n^2).

```
merged = []

for item in data:
    item_set = set(map(tuple, item))
    for result in merged:
        if result & item_set:
            result.update(item_set)
            break
    else:
        merged.append(item_set)

merged = [sorted(map(list, item)) for item in merged]
print(merged)
```

Comment: This works perfectly @Niel Godfrey Ponciano. Even with the real data it works as required. Many many thanks. I have been battling with this for the past 4 days.

Comment: Still checking through and realize it fails though, if the data pattern is reversed (which is how the original data behaves if viewed from the reverse direction) as such : data = [[[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]],[[0,1],[2,3]],[[0,1]], [[6,7],[8,9],[10,11]],[[6,7],[8,9]],[[6,7]], [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]],[[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19]],[[12,13],[14,15],[16,17]],[[12,13],[14,15]],[[12,13]]]. Can you figure out where the problem could be coming coming from? @Niel Godfrey Ponciano

Comment: I tried your input `data = [[[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]],[[0,1],[2,3]],[[0,1]], [[6,7],[8,9],[10,11]],[[6,7],[8,9]],[[6,7]], [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]],[[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19]],[[12,13],[14,15],[16,17]],[[12,13],[14,15]],[[12,13]]]` and it correctly resulted to `[[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]], [[6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11]], [[12, 13], [14, 15], [16, 17], [18, 19], [20, 21]]]` Could you check this? https://paiza.io/projects/e/k-jm2GcgyJf6IUQikfL8pA?theme=twilight

Comment: Oh sorry, that one works but this is what the reversed data looks like: data = [
            [[0,1]],
            [[0,1],[2,3]],
            [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]], 
            [[6,7]],
            [[6,7],[8,9]],
            [[6,7],[8,9],[10,11]], 
            [[12,13]],
            [[12,13],[14,15]],
            [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17]],
            [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19]],
            [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]]
            ]

Comment: Ok understood. Could you retry the updated solution on all possible combinations?

Comment: Perfect! Just perfect!! The update works for all combinations. A little more complex but does the job. I think I can cope with that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this loop:

```
newdata = []
for lst in data:
    if newdata:
        x = [i for i in lst if i not in newdata[-1]]
        if x:
            newdata.append(x)
    else:
        newdata.append(lst)
print(newdata)
```

Output:

```
[[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]], [[6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11]], [[12, 13], [14, 15], [16, 17], [18, 19], [20, 21]]]
```

Comment: Thanks much @U12-Forward , but this failed when I adapted it to the real data.

Comment: Worked for two combinations of the sample data but failed with these combination. data = [
            [[4,5]],
            [[2,3],[4,5]],
            [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]], 
            [[10,11]],
            [[8,9],[10,11]],
            [[6,7],[8,9],[10,11]], 
            [[20,21]],
            [[18,19],[20,21]],
            [[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]],
            [[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]],
            [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]]
            ]

Comment: And this: data = [
            [[0,1]],
            [[0,1],[2,3]],
            [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]], 
            [[6,7]],
            [[6,7],[8,9]],
            [[6,7],[8,9],[10,11]], 
            [[12,13]],
            [[12,13],[14,15]],
            [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17]],
            [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19]],
            [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]]
            ]

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

try this,

```
def sort_list(data):
    data = sorted(data, key=itemgetter(0))
    return_list = []
    for lst in data:
        new_list = sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(0))
        if not return_list:
            return_list.append(new_list)
            continue
        if new_list[0] not in return_list[-1]:
            return_list.append(new_list)
        if new_list[0] in return_list[-1] and len(new_list) > 
                                                len(return_list[-1]):
            return_list.remove(return_list[-1])
            return_list.append(new_list)
    return return_list
```

so you can sort the list

```
data = [[],
    [[0,1],[2,3]],
    [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]], 
    [[2,3],[4,5]], 
    [[4,5]], 
    [[6,7],[8,9],[10,11]], 
    [[8,9],[10,11]], 
    [[10,11]], 
    [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]], 
    [[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]], 
    [[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]],
    [[18,19],[20,21]],
    [[20,21]]
   ]
```

to

```
[[],
 [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]],
 [[6, 7], [8, 9], [10, 11]],
 [[12, 13], [14, 15], [16, 17], [18, 19], [20, 21]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts. The solution works for first given combination but fails with this data combination: data = [
            [[4,5]],
            [[2,3],[4,5]],
            [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]], 
            [[10,11]],
            [[8,9],[10,11]],
            [[6,7],[8,9],[10,11]], 
            [[20,21]],
            [[18,19],[20,21]],
            [[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]],
            [[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]],
            [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]]
            ].  It also fails with some combinations of the main data

Comment: Good effort @sarath ravi. Updated version works for all combinations of the sample data, and some combinations of the real data. However, it still fails in some combinations of the real data.

Comment: can you please provide the failure data. just to solve the issue

Comment: Here are the 4 possible combinations of the data, using the sample data. If it works for all 4, then it would certainly work for the original data. data = [
            [[0,1]],
            [[0,1],[2,3]],
            [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]], 
            [[6,7]],
            [[6,7],[8,9]],
            [[6,7],[8,9],[10,11]], 
            [[12,13]],
            [[12,13],[14,15]],
            [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17]],
            [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19]],
            [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]]
            ]

Comment: data = [
            [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]], 
            [[2,3],[4,5]], 
            [[4,5]], 
            [[6,7],[8,9],[10,11]], 
            [[8,9],[10,11]], 
            [[10,11]], 
            [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]], 
            [[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]], 
            [[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]],
            [[18,19],[20,21]],
            [[20,21]],
            ]

Comment: data = [
            [[4,5]],
            [[2,3],[4,5]],
            [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]], 
            [[10,11]],
            [[8,9],[10,11]],
            [[6,7],[8,9],[10,11]], 
            [[20,21]],
            [[18,19],[20,21]],
            [[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]],
            [[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]],
            [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]]
            ]

Comment: Lastly, 
data = [    
            [[0,1],[2,3],[4,5]],
            [[0,1],[2,3]],
            [[0,1]], 
            [[6,7],[8,9],[10,11]],
            [[6,7],[8,9]],
            [[6,7]], 
            [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19],[20,21]],
            [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17],[18,19]],
            [[12,13],[14,15],[16,17]],
            [[12,13],[14,15]],
            [[12,13]]
        ]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236656/discussion-between-fonnie-and-sarath-ravi).